# Link not displaying in edited question

Tags: bug

I edited [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/91413/creating-a-usb-to-rs485-converter-with-ft232rl-chip) to embed the image, either the user didn't have enough reputation or they didn't know how to.  Edit [log is here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/91413/revisions).

I noticed the image was quite squashed so I added a link below to click for a bigger version.  The edit preview showed the link and I clicked on it to check it worked.

When the edit was eventually approved the link didn't show.  I assumed I had done something silly so edited it again, removed the whole thing and tried a second time.

However the link isn't shown in the question even though it was displayed in the preview and is still visible in the Markdown source.  I used the WSIWYG editor buttons in all instances to add links and embed the image.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a feature/bug?

Answer (score 4):

I edited the question making the image clickable, check it for reference. The syntax is (one of the possible options):

```
[![`imagename`](`imageurl`)](link)
```

Comment: Thanks - that's very useful for future reference.  Still interested why the Markdown that the WSIWYG editor generated did not display correctly though.

Answer (score 1):

I just went and edited that question.

First, if you're going to insert a image, use the image upload facility built into SE so that the link can't rot.  That copies the image to imgur.

Second, there is no need for a explicit *click here for full size version* link since the image itself serves that purpose.  This may differ between browsers, but in IE you can right click on the image and select *save as*, which then copies it to your disk where you can examine it all you want.

Third, if you're in there editing it anyway, you might as well clean up other junk like the stupid "Thanks in advance for your help" or whatever at the end.

Comment: I did not insert the image, I simply embedded the image from a remote URL that was already in the question.  Sure you can save as but that's a pain when a linked image can be easily opened in a new tab with Ctrl-LeftClick.  Good advice on the third point, will remember to take a thorough look over the whole question next time I edit.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah OK, I can see the point of having something to click on to have the browser show you the image without scaling. I like Clabacchio's answer to that. However, always copy such images to imgur by using the image upload feature. That way the link can't rot. Include a link to the original page if you want to give proper credit.

Comment: Got it, will do that next time so that questions stand a chance of being useful long term.  Thanks again.